How can I set custom coloring for individual charts in Superset version 3.1?
In Superset version 3.1, I'm attempting to set individual colors for the charts on my dashboard, but the changes aren't taking effect, even when I don't set any color scheme for the dashboard itself.And I am unable to set the color scheme by modifying the dashboard's JSON metadata in Superset.
enter image description here
I hope to be able to set individual color schemes for the charts within my dashboard and have those settings take effect on the dashboard itself.
